# no connection error in samsung S5830

Tags: application-autoupdate

"I have a SAMSUNG GALAXY Ace S5830
in which market and you tube are showing a 'no connection' error while google is working properly " what should i do?

Comment: Which Android version is running on that device? Do other networking-related apps work normally (e.g. can you use mail/Gmail)? How is your network coverage? Are you working via WiFi or mobile data?

Answer (score 0):

You say Android "Market", which is an old version of Google Play. The Ace is an older device, and I imagine that in your case it's just been reset to factory settings, so many old versions of applications remain. These need updating.

The Market app should be updated automatically. Once that's done, then you'll be able to update You Tube and any other.

I had a Galaxy Ace and had to update eventually.